# FastCGI server error 500

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, fastcgi, plesk

I have an Ubuntu virtual server where I host my php website with the newest version of Plesk 12 and PHP 5.5. Sometimes (I believe when I open pages quickly one after another), I get an Internal Server error message..

When I refresh the page, the site is normal again immediatly, but sometimes the error message dissappears after about one minute later.

this is what I get on the page:

> Internal Server Error 500.
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.

Error log:

> [fcgid:warn] [pid 26583] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client (ip
>   address)] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer:
>   (url here)
>
> [core:error] [pid 26583] [client (ip address)] End of script output
>   before headers: index.php, referer: (same url here)

Answer (score 1):

Given your error log it looks like the index page wanted to write an HTTP header (with either header() or set_cookie or similar) AFTER it printed regular output, in your case probably a warning message due to an interrupted connection.

What I would try to do is disable all error output in the page with the php.ini, but still log the errors.

PHP can only output HTTP header fields *before* any other regular output, warning and error messages on the page included. So if you direct all errors and warnings only to the log files, and *NOT* print them on the page, there will be no output before the HTTP header and it should work fine.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
I have indeed several header() functions after header has been declared on some pages, wich usually works fine with ob_start().
I disabled all error output but the internal server error is still occuring.

Comment: ok, the next debugging step would be to increase error log level and print all log output to the log file. I assume that the second line in the log output does not appear any more with deactivated error output. so now you need to figure out at which point exactly the php script dies. you can do this by adding error_log statements to the script. try also to increase the maximum allowed memory consumption per script in the pho.ini. this is a common source of problems in PHP (although that would be logged usually).

Comment: sorry for the late response. unfortunately I couldnt follow the error logging steps exactly as I'm not a real pro in it. I changed error_reporting to ~E_ALL, if this is right? memory_limit is currently at 256M. (should I increase?). But one thing I discovered: I just created a new php file with only a html link in it, and opened this  same file quickly one after another each in a new tab and got the same internal server error. but a lot lot rarer though (because of small file size?). maybe the failure is not in the script but in the server?

Answer (score 1):

If *any* PHP script causes an error, try following this procedure:

1. Switch from FastCGI to CGI
2. Trigger an error with another request
3. Inspect `error_log` for actual errors, fix them accordingly
4. Switch back to FastCGI

If configuration files like `apache.conf` have an error in them **it will not appear in the error log** with FastCGI on.